# Reducing the length of a long url string (compress/encrypt) before restoring it

Tags: php, gzip

I'm wondering if there's a solution to my problem. I've been searching and found a few answers which match but haven't 100% worked for my example.

I have a randomly generated string of characters which are typically 300-500 characters long, consisting of 0-9, A-Z, a-z and also dash "-" and underscore "_". I can't change the length of this unfortunately. I need to pass it in a url and store it in a database which has a maximum character length of 255.

I've tried using gzdeflate and gzinflate but I believe this gives an unusable output which can't be passed in a url or stored in a db. And it seemed that the output was just as long as the input. Maybe I didn't code it properly.

```
    $input = "E.C.P.CsMBcgiZIFc2xMHNxPxdrHyXiq34ZVVTKLIG19xj8cGxQjRQE9eS1W8ofrkrdYrt-XyEiYzBpVxf-iWeKcp6yGM5PI4QnJQCVRdNjcM5QbsTjYGPbnbOgoua9EVU9kDWDAznLvaXkFG-3wvy07kEPjogANMqVkX5cfikWQnLL5PMIqkm5z7bBDFdwHjy-Faos9e9_t4zshZN7gKN2RAiYYc-FLivga_iZNX4CiYj4-F4trloW--Zyo_Mn59wkvQ2HPrPjcPREgR2Mi4wGiDODXxTAuoEDRmLgV1R41zrL6cr5M2Z6N5LPxxfRwO2DQ";

    echo "Input:", $input . "\n";

    $compressed = gzdeflate($input,  9);

    echo "Compressed:", $compressed . "\n";

    $output = gzinflate($compressed);

    echo "Output:", $output . "\n";
```

So then I tried using base64_encode to make a usable url string, but it was just as large as the original.

Any pointers would be great.

Thanks
Glen

Comment: Why not enlarge the field? base64 usually adds about 1/3 of the length, and then you can better skip the compression completely

Comment: A random string like that doesn't compress very well, no matter what algorithm you use. In short: What you're trying to do is impossible.

Comment: I agree, why not just make the database field bigger, it's by far the simplest and quickest solution. And as also mentioned, compression is unlikely to be effective on this sort of data anyway. And base64 is encoding, not compression. In some cases it can actually make the payload larger.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. We have requested that the developer increase the size of the database field. But still waiting on word back. Just trying to come up with a workaround for the short term or in case they say they won't increase it.

Comment: Really you should insist on them changing the size. It's a trivial alteration and, realistically, if they won't then you're going to have to go back to whoever wants you to do this work with the URL and tell them it's not possible because of an arbitrary and unnecessary limitation imposed by someone else who won't alter it, despite it being simple to do so. I can't imagine that's a conversation anyone will enjoy

Comment: Your example also has periods.

Comment: Can there be conversion applied between reception on the other end and entry into the database? What are the allowed characters in the database entry?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to reduce 300 random characters from that set to 255 URL-safe characters, even if I am liberal in considering what characters are safe.

You have 64 possible characters in your claimed set, though there are 65 in your example, which has some periods. This is 6 to 6.022 bits of information per character (take the logarithm base 2). If I allow the set of URL safe, unreserved, *and* reserved characters, I can use 92 characters, which can convey 6.52 bits per character. (All of the reserved set may not work depending on how your URL is processed by your server.) Then the theoretical maximum possible compression would be a factor of 0.92 (6 / 6.52), which would take your 300 characters down to 276 characters.

So no.

If you are able to send your data as is (URI's can be over 2000 characters), *and* you can insert some processing between reception and entry into the database, *and* you can put binary data in your database entry, then you could reduce your 300 to 500 characters down to 225 to 375 bytes. Though still not less than 256 on the high end.